# Error in importing the numbers in scientific notation

Tags: microsoft-excel, macbook-pro, microsoft-excel-2011

I am importing(copy-paste) values into Excel from R Console which are in scientific notation (1.920943e-10, 7.580894e-05). Excel is not treating them as numbers instead text. How to resolve this ?

Thanks

**Edit:**
The problem is with the entire workbook. I'm not able to paste the image as it needs min of 10 reputation.

Comment: Could you add more info on specifically how you are importing the values?

Answer (score 0):

When you enter then cell with the value stored is there a visible leading apostrophe? like this:

```
'1.920943e-10
```

If so, delete it.

If not, try right click>format cells> choose a number format

Finally an option that will work if all else fails is to put in a second column in your sheet.  Where

```
A1= 1.920943e-10

A2 should be
=value(A1)
```

Should do the trick no problem.

If you don't want that column in your end sheet, the select it, copy, and paste special>paste as values.

This will paste the value of the formula and you can delete the source infomation (i.e. column 1) and just keep the converted data (column 2)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried them but didn't work out !

Comment: what happened with =value(A1)?

Comment: i have got the error  `#VALUE!`

Comment: OK, can you take a screen shot with the cell with a problem number in it  highlighted?